# confusing with arraytlist output

Tags: java

How come the output is:

```
A
C
```

Since it will read all the indexes

```
ArrayList<String> g =new ArrayList<>();
g.add("A");
g.add("B");
g.add("C");
g.add("D");

for(int i=0;i<g.size();i++){
    System.out.println(g.remove(i));
}
```

Comment: the answer without the \n but the B is in new line

Comment: I advice you not to remove elements in loop directly when using collections use iterator for the job that would be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
0 1 2 3
A B C D
```

`g.size()` at this point is 4.

You print `A` and then remove it. Now we have:

```
0 1 2
B C D
```

And `i` is 2. You print `B` and remove C (at index 1).

Now we have:

```
0 1
C D
```

But `g.size()` is now 2, and `i == 2`, so `i < g.size()` doesn't hold and the loop won't execute, leaving you with this output.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, by the time you reach at index 2 (till B) the size has been reduced to 2 and thus the for loop ends there printing till B itself!

Comment: sorry bro it is A C

Comment: you may check the size as well in the loop.  for(int i=0;i<g.size();i++){
         
      System.out.println(g.remove(i) + " :: " + g.size());
         }

Comment: then it should print A B C but the output only A C

Comment: @Maroun has given the entire flow of the program. I thought you were just confused as why not the entire list got printed. So may be the hint was enough!

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration in the for loop removes an element in the list.. so

```
i<g.size()
```

Is changing for every new iteration ..

Remember **g** is getting shorter